# Unable to connect to worker role using RDP

Tags: azure, rdp

I am using a Cloud services running a single worker role with two instances. For almost a year I have been able to connect using RDP.

This week I wanted to connect, but couldn't. The remote desktop connection display the wrong credentials displaying: "Use the following credentials to connect: Password for Admin"

When an deployment is uploaded to the staging environment, I am able to connect. After swapping to the production environment, I cann't connect.
But the old deployment can be connected in the staging environment.

When I set up the connection from another PC, I am able to connect.

I think there is something going on with my PC, but no idea where to look.

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out I have checked "Save my credentials" by accident. There was an entry in the Windows Credential Manager. 
Deleted the entry, I can connect again.

Answer (score 0):

After creating the RDP account, I had to reimage the webrole (Roles And Instances -> WebRole -> Reimage). After the reimage I was able to connect.